# Typescript Cannot find type definition file for 'mapbox'

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm still fairly new to type script and I am struggling with module declerations for types,

Was wondering if anyone would be able to help with the following errors

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'abitype'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'abitype'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mapbox'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'mapbox'
```

here is the filestructure

```
./types
├── abitype
│   └── abi.d.ts
└── mapbox
    └── mapbox-gl-draw.d.ts
```

abi.d.ts

```
import "abitype";

declare module "abitype" {
  export interface Config {
    AddressType: string;
  }
}
```

mapbox-gl-draw.d.ts

```
declare module "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw";
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    // disable this if you want to use any
    // "noImplicitAny": false
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"], // <----------------- here I have set the type roots
    "paths": {
      "~~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've tried altering the tsconfig and module declerations